# modeling a proportion with seasonality removed

Tags: generalized-linear-model, proportion, seasonality

I have a time series of proportions that typically fall in the 0.01-0.05 range. I had intended to use GLM to model these proportions, but I ran into trouble when I needed to first remove a strong seasonal component in the data. After deseasonalization, the response is often negative, so I can't treat it as a proportion anymore. Does this mean I should just treat it as a simple linear response?

Comment: Probably not. There are time-series methods for proportions. Do you have continuous proportions or are the proportions of successes out of a known number of trials?